# dynamic mybatis xml query

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Need help with following dynamic query:

```
if country==null OR country != (spain || Peru)
select * from emp where country NOT IN (spain,Peru)
else
select * from emp where country=#{country}
```

I tried something like this but its not helping:

```
<when test="country ==null" or country !='spain' or country != 'Peru'">
            AND country NOT IN ('spain','peru')
            </when>
            <otherwise>
            AND country=#{country}
 </otherwise>
```

Always generate NOT IN even if country=us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<when test="country !='spain' and country != 'uk'">
```

wrong condition, expected and instead of or

Answer (score 1):

try this `test="country == null or country != 'spain' or country != 'UK' "`

Comment: always generating NOT IN

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotation to string.

```
<when test='country == null or !country.equals("spain") or !country.equals("uk")'>
        AND country NOT IN ('spain','uk')
        </when>
        <otherwise>
        AND country=#{country}
 </otherwise>
```